# Is there a way to separate parts of a String that is separated by filter units?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing this program where the output below is saved to a text file

Unresolved%Bob%NA%Smith%123%8

and opened up by a separate VB program. the text above is then made into a string

"Unresolved%Bob%NA%Smith%123%8" = String1

I now need to get each part separated by the % into it's own string. ex.

"Unresolved" = string1a

"Bob" = string1b

"NA" = string1c

and so on. So my question is, is this possible and how? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

With the [`String.Split`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjXrPX-mPjHAhUIK4gKHXzIALM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.split(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHqx3_8pArbFO3N2mC42khDG79MSw&sig2=97zIpJeYRghOwhrR6Q2xzw&bvm=bv.102537793,d.cGU) method.

```
 Dim input As String = "Unresolved%Bob%NA%Smith%123%8"
 'make the string array
 Dim output() As String = input.Split("%"c)
```

Now you have an array of all the parts.

Load them into memory - create an object to pars the data into:

```
Public Class Client
  Public Property FirstName As String
  Public Property MiddleName As String
  Public Property LastName As String
  Public Property Status As String
  Public Property Value1 As String
  Public Property Value2 As String
End Class
```

In method that parses the data:

```
 Dim input As String = "Unresolved%Bob%NA%Smith%123%8"
 'make the string array
 Dim output() As String = input.Split("%"c)
 Dim _client As New Client
 _client.Status = output(0)
 _client.FirstName = output(1)
 _client.MiddleName = output(2)
 _client.LastName = output(3)
 _client.Value1 = output(4)
 _client.Value2 = output(5)
```

After all that being said, you could parse lines from a file and add them into a collection if needed.

Comment: Once I have the output array how do I use it as a variable?

Comment: Make a class object and fill it with the values -update to answer.